# How to read StateNotifierProvider state inside FutureProvider

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a `StateNotifierProvider` which has getter and setter method of a class variable.
I'm trying to access the class variable value via getter method inside a `FutureProvider`
I've tried multiple ways to access the value inside the FutureProvider but unable to get any success.

I am getting the below error
[errror snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVJD3.jpg)
Let me know the correct approach.

```
class SelectedPost extends StateNotifier<String> {
  SelectedPost() : super("");
  var uuid;
  void setPostId(String id) {
    uuid = id;
  
  }

  String getPostId() {
    return uuid;
    
  }
}
```

Here I'm trying to access the getter method to fetch `uuid` value

```
final selectedPostProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) =>  new SelectedPost());

final detailPostFuture = FutureProvider<Post>((ref) async {
  final _selectedPostProvider = ref.watch(selectedPostProvider);

  return fetchDetailPost(_selectedPostProvider.getPostId());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the state itself, use this.

```dart
final detailPostFuture = FutureProvider<Post>((ref) async {
  final _selectedPostProvider = ref.watch(selectedPostProvider);
});
```

If you want to access only the members (like functions, variables), use this.

```dart
final detailPostFuture = FutureProvider<Post>((ref) async {
  final _selectedPostProvider = ref.watch(selectedPostProvider.notifier);
});
```

If you want to use both, use this.

```dart
final detailPostFuture = FutureProvider<Post>((ref) async {
  final _selectedPostState = ref.watch(selectedPostProvider);

  final _selectedPostProvider = ref.watch(selectedPostProvider.notifier);
});
```

See [this](https://riverpod.dev/docs/migration/0.13.0_to_0.14.0#the-changes) migration doc for reference.

Comment: How does the state gives the value of uuid via getter method?

Comment: You can access any class members with `_selectedPostProvider` from the last code snippet. For example, `_selectedPostProvider.uuid`, will give `uuid` property. I'll encourage you to understand the difference between state of the `StateNotifier` and class members. There are many tutorials on `StateNotifier`. You can start from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/state_notifier).

Comment: How about accessing the getter method where it's not working? Any explanation on that?

Comment: @RajanChauhan Can you explain `where it's not working` part? Where and how are you accessing it? Which getter function? Need more context.

Comment: This line `return fetchDetailPost(_selectedPostProvider.getPostId())`

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, we can access any member of the class. So for `getPostId`, use `_selectedPostProvider.getPostId()`. Also, I was confused when you mentioned this as a getter. You might be using this function to get a value of a variable but this is not a getter function by definition. [This](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#getters-and-setters) explains getters and setters in dart.

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch the Notifier itself. It can be done by using:

```
final _selectedPostNotifier = ref.watch(selectedPostProvider.notifier);
```